# Calling child component dynamically until a condition is met

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-jest, lwc-wire-getlistui

I have recently started coding in LWC and I have a use case that -> I need to call this `c-component2` repeatedly from `mycomponent1.html until a condition is met. Is there something I can do to achieve this?

First we call normally by triggering ValidateRun=true. Now in `initialCall`, i need to call `c-component2` until a condition is met.

**mycomponent1.html**

```
<template if:true={ValidateRun}>
  <c-component2 attr1="val1" attr2="get" attr3={val3} onevent={initialCall}></c-component2>
</template>
<template if:true={pollStart}>
  <c-component2 attr1="val4" attr2="val5" attr3={val6} onevent={eventDetails}></c-component2>
</template>
```

**mycomponent1.js**

```
initialCall(event){
  this.pollStart = true;
  //Here i need to keep on execute my c-component2 code until a condition is satisfied.
}
```

Comment: Why are you polling it? Shouldn't you trigger this once and let the child component handle it, and just wait for an event?

Comment: @CasparHarmer I need to execute this child component until a condition is met. The child component execution will return some values. So these values would take time.

Comment: How is the condition met? A database query or a callout? Both can be handled with an async function / promise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` in `connectedCallback()` to schedule the `initialCall()` method to be called at a regular time interval, say 1 second.

In the `initialCall()` method check if the required condition is true, in that case clear the timer.

```js
  timer;
  connectedCallback() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.initialCall();
    }, 1000);
  }

  initialCall() {
    this.template.querySelector('c-child-component')?.childMethod();
    if (<condition to check>) clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case i need to call the `<c-component2 attr1="val4" attr2="val5" attr3={val6} onevent={eventDetails}></c-component2>` repeatedly along with my attributes, here how to specify the same? `this.template.querySelector('c-child-component');` and no need of connectedcallback as i will set the initial call function to be true progrramatically.